# Bounding entries of random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Given a random vector $\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible to count (or bound) the number of entries in $\mathbf{e}$ that have $|e_i| \ge 1/ \sqrt{n}$? It is known that entries in $\mathbf{e}$ are independent.

In particular I want to bound the expected number of such entries to conclude that they almost surely no such entries occur.  My intention was to define an indicator variable that is 1 if and only if entry $|e_i| \ge 1/ \sqrt{n}$ and then use Markov's inequality but I haven't had much luck with this.

Comment: How are you choosing $e$?  What distribution are you using?

Comment: i've written $\mathbf{e} = u_2 - v_2$.  The vector $u_2$ is a block vector that is $1/ \sqrt{n}$ on the first $n/2$ entries, and the negative of that on the remaining entries.  The vector $v_2$ is the second eigenvector of a random planted partition model graph on two blocks so has two binomial distributions $Bin((n-1)/2,p)$ and $Bin(n/2,q)$.  All edges to form the graph are chosen randomly.